# Express Validator Cannot Show Error Mesages

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator, connect-flash

Hey guys I want to make an messaging system for my upload webpage.

I use express-validator and connect-flash, express-messages

**app.js**

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
.
.
.
app.post('/metin/ekle', [
  // username must be an email
  check('baslik', 'Baslik Gereklidir').notEmpty(),
  // password must be at least 5 chars long
  check('konu','Konu gereklidir').notEmpty(),
],function(req, res){

  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    req.flash('danger', { errors: errors.array() });//I dont know what do do exactly here
  }

    var metin = new Metin({
      baslik: req.body.baslik,
      yazar: req.body.yazar,
      konu: req.body.konu,
    });

        metin.save(function(err){
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
          } else {
            req.flash('success', 'Metin Eklendi');
            res.redirect("/metin/"+ metin._id);
          }
        });
      });
```

And this is my article.pug:

```
!= messages('my_message_template', locals)
    if errors
        each error, i in errors
          div(class="alert alert-danger") #{error.msg}
```

> ReferenceError: msg is not defined

I dont know what to do exaclty where I decleared validationResult errs. I wrote msg but I know it is wrong. What can I or change my codes in order to message danger when I get express-validation errors?

Answer (score 0):

You need change that below line

```
req.flash({msg});//I dont know what do do exactly here
```

To

```
return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
```

then in the view you can find something like that:

```
{
"errors": [{
    "location": "body",
    "msg": "Invalid value",
    "param": "username"
}]
}
```

You can see the `express-validator` docs [here](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/)

Thanks

Comment: Yes I have done this but it doesnt show the messages just like here express mesages if err. I want to make a message system just like this system shows

Comment: It show just like this {"errors":[{"value":"","msg":"Baslik Gereklidir","param":"baslik","location":"body"},{"value":"","msg":"Konu gereklidir","param":"konu","location":"body"}]}

Comment: Yes, I think it was expected

Comment: Yes but I want to make it with connect-flash and express-message