# Bcrypt And PassportJs User Registration

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, bcrypt

I am not sure about if I am us,ng bcrypt correctly.

This is my code that I tried to write.

```
app.post('/kayıt/', function(req, res){
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        let user = new User({
        isim:req.body.isim,
        email:req.email.isim,
        password:req.body:password,
});
user.save(function(err){
if(err){
  console.log(err);
}else{
res.redirect('/');
});
```

Do you think that are there any errors ? Or the usage of bcrypt and user registration process made correctly.(Note: In my procet I have stuck in another code blocks about express-validator, so that I tried to write a code but I am not sure if it is correct or not)

So that can you tell me about these codes, if it is wrong what should I change, if it is not what elses are alternative to write this registration part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple methods to `hash` a password using `bcrypt.js`. Like you can use `Promise`, `async`, `sync`. The one that you used is `async` that generates `salt` and `hash` on a separate function calls. One error in your code is it should be `password:req.body.password` you need to use `dot(.)` after `body` instead of `colon(:)`.

Besides your code one of the methods to hash a password is

```
 router.post('/kayıt', async (req, res) => {
     //hashed password 
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

    const user = new User({
       isim: req.body.isim,
       email: req.body.email,
       password: hashedPassword
    });
    user.save(function(err) {
             if (err) {
                console.log(err);
             } else {
                res.redirect('/');
               }
             });
         });
```

You can have a look [here](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/).

Comment: Can I ask that if I implement my own code, will it work ?

Comment: so what are the differecense between my code and your code ?

Comment: Your code is `async` that generates a salt and hash on separate function calls. And I have used `Async/await`

Comment: And after I impement I can do correctly login system write?

Comment: These codes is used to store `isim`, `email` and `hashed password` in database

Comment: And could you pelase look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922186/express-validator-cannot-show-error-mesages Please

Comment: @kedar sedai Sir I get the error of  SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
Why this is happening? Could you please help me?

Comment: Just add `async` in front of `callback function` code is updated have a look

Comment: Okey the problem is gone, Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Sir can you please look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62155742/passportjs-and-mongodb-user-cannot-used-properly please. Because the question also relevant with these scrits.

Comment: Sorry I deleted it. It is now here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62167716/passportjs-gives-error-of-missing-credentials